# Unable to access QRCode OR QRCodeGenerator.QRCode class while using QRCoder library version 1.3.5

Tags: qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am unable to access QRCode class OR QRCodeGenerator.QRCode, while I am using QRCode.dll version 1.3.5 or I have checked version 1.3.3 but getting same issue.

```
 public void GenerateQRCode(string code)
    {
        var imgUrl="";
        //string code = txtCode.Text;
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();

        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(code, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);

        QRCode  qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData); 

        // I am getting error in above line, or I am using below line of code but getting error. Unable to access QRCode withQRCodeGenerator.

        QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(code, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);

        using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray(); 
                imgUrl= "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Above is the code which I am using in web API 2

Comment: I'm using v. 1.4.3 and have the same problem with a .Net Core 6 project.